# How to use CountIf in Google Sheets that only counts cells if there is content in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I need some help with a CountIf type formula in Google Sheets.

I have a large spreadsheet of a consolidated NHL schedule where I am going to enter stats that I care about. In a separate spreadsheet I am going to have averages for the stats I care about.

I want to have a formula that uses the Column A of Sheet2 to count the games in Sheet1 that have content in the other cells of Sheet1 (so, games that have been played).

If this works then Column B of Sheet2 will have the correct # of games played which is all the cells that have content/stats next to the teams name in Sheet1 so that I dont have to manually update that part and then the count of games played can go straight to the average formula.

The pictures are manually entered but just showing that since the Blackhawks have content next to their name in Sheet1, I would want Sheet2 Column B to read 1 based on a formula.

Thanks!!!

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6WGy.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SILO7.png)

Comment: Are the stats limited to columns D to H or could there be more columns?

Comment: `c` in `Sheet1!F6` stands for "content", eg 1x `c` = `1` in `Sheet2!B3` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would just do a COUNTA on a column (so that counts the rows in a specific column that are not blank), on a filtered table that match the team names:

So:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!B:B=A3))
```

[image]

[image]